# Is there a way to authorize users with existing account only?

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, google-signin

Iam working on a flutter mobile application where i use Google SignIn for Auth, is there a way to authorize users with existing account only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prevent users from creating new accounts? I've looked for the same thing without finding a way to do this with any Firebase project setting.

The solution, I believe, is consider the difference between *authentication* and *authorization*. Firebase's Authentication service is aptly named. It does *authentication* 
 - validates that a user is actually who they claim to be. It does not do *authorization* - control what actions authenticated users are allowed to perform or what data they can access within an application. App developers have to be responsible for managing user *authorization*.

One way to do this is to maintain a collection of "authorized users" in Firestore, for example. When a user *authenticates*, your app would perform a lookup to see if the current user is actually *authorized* or not. Security rules can be written for Firestore and Firebase Cloud Storage to also validate that the current user is in the "authorized users" collection before allowing access to data. But this requires extra data queries to obtain this authorization info.

The authorization method I prefer is to use Custom Claims which can be assigned using the Firebase Admin library. A custom claim can be added to an existing user account that can act as a flag indicating what type of authorization they're granted. Front-end code can check the authentication token they've been issued for the custom claim to determine the authorization they've been granted. Server-side code and security rules can also check for those required custom claims within submitted requests.

Realistically, any application you build where different users might have different levels of access will require you to deal with authorization. I believe that assigning carefully thought-out custom claims is the best solution.